# Vis.js network: how to extract customized options of a node (and an edge)?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm developing a simplistic graph editor using vis.js/network. Since an editor has to store the network state, I have a saving helper where I extract data from a network and store it as JSON.

For now, I use seemingly quite an ugly/hacky way to extract data for storage:

```
// get nodes and edges
var nodes = network.body.data.nodes._data; // brief ones; network.body.nodes contain much more stuff (x,y, default stuff)
//# look for a suitable getter
var edges = network.body.data.edges._data;
// network.body.data.edges._data is a hash of { id: , from: , to: }

// get node positions
var positions = network.getPositions(),
    nodeIds = Object.keys(nodes);

var storedEdges = [], storedNodes = [];
for(var edgeId in edges)
    storedEdges.push({ from: edges[edgeId].from, to: edges[edgeId].to });
for(var nodeId in nodes) {
    storedNodes.push({
        id: nodes[nodeId].id, label: nodes[nodeId].label,
        x: positions[nodeId].x, y: positions[nodeId].y
    })
}
```

As you can see, I manually extract those properties (`id`, `label`, `x`, `y`) and set to the `storedNodes` for each node (or edge). What I need is to save also changed properties – only those non-default (customized) ones. Like if some edge has an `arrows` set to `"to"` I'd like to save that (but not `arrows:false` for each other edge); or if a node has a customized shape or color, I'd like to save that without saving all colors, shapes, font sizes etc etc for each node.

So, my question is: how do I get the customized properties of a node? Is there some helper for that? Or do I have to iterate and compare a couple of trees (default options and actual options)? Any suggestions?

PS ok, looking through [the whole list of methods](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#methods) tells me that most probably there's no real helpers for this task (except may be `getOptionsFromConfigurator` if it works without configurator but it seems that it only tells the global options, not those of nodes or edges). So I'll check `getOptionsFromConfigurator` and then move to searching which properties to iterate and compare. `network.body.nodes[id].nodeOptions` and `network.body.edges[id].edgeOptions` look promising. Another thing to look at is using `vis.DataSet` (I should try to access `nodes` created as `new vis.DataSet(nodes)` and see if they get default options and customized options).

Comment: Did you manage to get?

Comment: @Neo partly yes, well at least I extract the styling data of a node (like color, font etc)