# Creating .json file and storing data in javascript -- using vis.js

Tags: javascript, json, vis.js, vis.js-network

In my project I need to save the data to .txt or .xml or .json file. I could not find any answer from vis.js website/issues blog. It might be simple, do not know. Really helpful if anyone help me out with example code. Thank you so much in advance.

```
function saveData(data,callback) {
  data.id = document.getElementById('node-id').value;
  data.label = document.getElementById('node-label').value;
  clearPopUp();
  callback(data);
}
```

Comment: I could make it using
        let dataStr = JSON.stringify(data);
        let dataUri = "....."
        let exportFileDefaultName = 'test.json';

Question is : Each node gets saving when I add. 
but would like to create the file after I finish add/edit/connect the nodes to edges. 
I see saveandload in vis.js. But it doesn't have any add/edit node network popup to add/edit my own properties/options. Could anyone please help me if this is possible or not. Thanks.

Comment: I didnt understand your question. You have a network that you can edit and then you want to save it's data on a file...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a way to save data and options of a graph. In my [graph editor adaptation for TiddlyWiki Classic](http://yakovl.bplaced.net/TW/GraphTools/GraphEditor.html) I use the following method to extract data (the full implementation can be found in the repo, see `config.macros.graph.saveDataAndOptions`, here's a simplified one):

```
config.macros.graph.saveDataAndOptions = function(network,newOptions) {

    newOptions = newOptions || {};

    // get nodes and edges
    var nodes = network.body.data.nodes._data; // contains id, label, x,y, custom per-node options and doesn't contain options from options.nodes; presumably contains option values set when network was created, not current ones (it is so for x,y)
    // no suitable getter unfortunately
    var edges = network.body.data.edges._data; // map; for edges to/from? certain node use network.getConnectedNodes(id)
    // network.body.data.edges._data is a hash of { id: , from: , to: }

    // get node positions, options
    var positions = network.getPositions(), // map
        options = // get options stored previously
    // merge newOptions into options

    for(var nodeId in nodes) {
        // nodes[nodeId].x is the initial value, positions[nodeId].x is the current one
        if(positions[nodeId]) { // undefined for hidden
            nodes[nodeId].x = positions[nodeId].x;
            nodes[nodeId].y = positions[nodeId].y;
        }
        storedNode = copyObjectProperties(nodes[nodeId]);

        storedNodes.push(storedNode);
    }

    //# do whatever you need with storedNodes, edges and options
    //  (pack them with JSON.stringify, store to a file etc)
};
```

However, while this works ok for storing data, this only helps to save options passed for storing explicitly which can be not very nice for some cases. I use this method in `manipulation` helpers and on dragEnd (`network.on("dragEnd",this.saveToTiddlerAfterDragging)`, `config.macros.graph.saveToTiddlerAfterDragging = function(stuff) {  config.macros.graph.saveDataAndOptions(this,{ physics: false }); };`). I [haven't recieved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45202967/3995261) any better suggestions, though.

If you need to get data and options reactively and setting such helper to handle certain edit events can't solve your problem, then I suggest wrapping `nodes`, `edges` and `options` as `vis.DataSet` and save those when needed. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47275045/3995261) is related too.

---

To answer the question about events/other ways to use such methods. Here's how I use them:

1. I save data after drag&drop moving of nodes, this is done using an event handler. Namely, I introduced

   ```
   config.macros.graph.saveToTiddlerAfterDragging = function(stuff) {
       config.macros.graph.saveDataAndOptions(this,{ physics: false });
   };
   ```

   (when drag&drop is used, physics should be switched off, otherwise coordinates won't be preserved anyway) and then I use

   ```
   network.on("dragEnd",this.saveToTiddlerAfterDragging);
   ```

   so that changes are saved.
2. As for saving after adding/editing a node/edge, I apply saving not by an event (although it's nice thinking, and you should try [events of DataSet](http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html#Events), since there's no special [graph events](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#Events) for that). What I do is I add an elaborated hijack to the manipulation methods. Take a look at the source I've linked after the

   ```
   var mSettings = options.manipulation;
   ```

   line: for each manipulation method, like `options.manipulation.addNode` I hijack it so that *its callback* is hijacked to call `config.macros.graph.saveDataAndOptions` in the end. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

   ```
   var nonSaving_addNode = options.manipulation.addNode;
   options.manipulation.addNode = function(data,callback) {
       // hijack callback to add saving
       arguments[1] = function() {
           callback.apply(this,arguments); // preserve initial action
           config.macros.graph.saveDataAndOptions(network); // add saving
       };
       nonSaving_addNode.apply(this,arguments);
   }
   ```

   The thing is, `addNode` is actually called when the add node button is clicked; though, I'm using a customized one to create a popup and apply changes once user is happy with the label they chose.

Comment: Yes, I need to save data(id, label and my own added fields) and options (edges-arows "from", "to") in a file. You made my day. Just woke up and saw your response :-)
Will try this code and reply back to you. Thank you so much again.

Comment: All your suggestions I could check the code and could save it in a file. (Actually each node gets a new file) and each connectionandoptions gets a new file. So only my only last file to be used for my project. here is my code --"i call a function  get_conn_edges" : 
          function saveData(data,callback) {
          data.id = document.getElementById('node-id').value;
          ..  my own additional fields value; .
 to save the details of the node(dataStr) to json file :
                       let dataStr = JSON.stringify(data);
            then I call  get_conn_edges();
         }

Comment: function savedataandedge () { 
                  var nodes = objectToArray(network.getPositions());
                         nodes.forEach(addConnections);
                var exportValue = JSON.stringify(nodes, undefined, 2);
let dataStr = JSON.stringify(exportValue.replace(/\r?\n|\r?\"/g, ''));

Comment: @Varun I suggest you to post additional code in your question using the "edit" button and post it formatted. I didn't get if you have some question regarding how to use the code I provided or something else, so please edit your initial post and let me know.

Comment: I edited my question. I'm looking forward to have your suggestion. 
From your code : I don't see any event or button click either.

Comment: @Varun take a look, I've added info that you're looking for